# Retrieve current Windows user in Java EE web application for Single Sign On purposes

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, active-directory, single-sign-on, windows-users

I am doing a Java EE web application that requires Single Sign On with Active Directory.

The application will no longer prompt for a username and password. The authentication process would require retrieval of the current Windows logged on user. Once I have the user, I need to query Active Directory to get the roles for that logged on user. I am aware that this will exclude non-Windows users, but this is an internal application and all clients are using Windows.

I have to implement the SSO in 2 Java EE web applications. 1 application is runnning on GlassFish v2.1.1 (JDK 1.6) and the other is running on Tomcat (JDK 1.5).

Basically my main problem is how to retrieve the current Windows logged on user.

I've already come across [JAAS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/tutorials/GeneralAcnOnly.html) and [Kerberos](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/KerberosReq.html). Kindly correct me if I'm wrong. My understanding is that these are authentication protocol and they do not have the feature to retrieve the current windows logged on user.

I've already tried the following but I am always getting `null` or Server's own username.

1. `System.getProperty("user.name");`
2. `new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem().getName();`
3. `request.getUserPrincipal().getName();`
4. `System.getenv("USERNAME");`
5. JCIF NTLM HTTP Authentication in Tomcat
6. LoginContext

I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Do you want the user who is logged on the client computer or the server computer?

Comment: I'd like the logged on user on the client machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[WAFFLE](http://dblock.github.io/waffle/README.html) is a great solution for this. It does not need Kerberos configuration.

Answer (score 3):

[**SPNEGO**](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/) is an open source project that provides a servlet filter that provies Integrated Windows Authentication.

> if your organization uses java based
>   web/application servers, and you
>   prefer Kerberos/SPNEGO instead of NTLM
>   as the authentication protocol, and
>   you would rather have a Java Servlet
>   Filter (JSR-53) based implementation
>   instead of a container specific
>   authentication module (JSR-196), and
>   you want SSO (no username/password
>   prompt), then this project may be of
>   some interest to you.

It has instructions for configuring both [Tomcat](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/spnego_tomcat.html) and [Glassfish](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/spnego_glassfish.html).

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:
http://webmoli.com/2009/08/29/single-sign-on-in-java-platform/
http://appliedcrypto.com/

Answer (score 0):

JCIFS NTLM is [no longer supported](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/ntlmhttpauth.html) (though it will work with NTLMv1). In  my current project we have used [SPNEGO](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/) as previosuly recommended.

Options 1, 2 & 3 will try to get you the server user - you might want to have a think about where this code is running & how it could interact with the client machine (hint - it can't)