# How to fetch the windows username from client machine using Java/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java

I have a JSP page where I need to fetch the current username logged into client machine.

Is there any way to get the windows username (client) by Java or javascript?

I found some article on the same topic but unfortunately none of them works in my case.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Check this: [Retrieve current Windows user in Java EE web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590227/retrieve-current-windows-user-in-java-ee-web-application-for-single-sign-on-purp), doesn't it work?

Comment: That smells like [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Why do you need Windows username?

Comment: I found a lot of articles by keyword='java servlet get os username' at google.

Comment: @Nina Scholz, Javascript should have no way to implement this. But Java servlet should have some solutions (check the link: [Retrieve current Windows user in Java EE web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590227/retrieve-current-windows-user-in-java-ee-web-application-for-single-sign-on-purp),)

Comment: I haven't found any solution till now using Servlet or Javascript. I am searching something like applet that could get the information from the client machine & pass it to any servlet.